# Python Dataframe for loop syntax

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

I'm having trouble in correctly executing a for loop through my dataframe in python.

Basically, for every row in the dataframe (df_weather), the code should select one value each from the column no. 13 and 14 and execute a function which is defined earlier in the code. Eventually, I require the calculated value in each row to be summed to give me one final answer.

The error being returned is as follows: "string indices must be integers"

Request anyone to help me through this step. The code for the same is provided below.

Thanks!

```
stress_rate = 0
for i in df_weather:
    b = GetStressDampHeatParameterized(i[:,13], i[:,14])
    stress_rate = b + stress_rate
print(stress_rate)
```

Comment: Can you post ```df_weather.head()```?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in a single line:

```
print sum(df.apply(lambda row: func(row[14], row[15]), axis=1))
```

Where *func* is your desired function and axis=1 ensures that the function is applied on each row as opposed to each column (which is the default).

My solution first creates a temporary series (picture: an unattached column) that is constructed by applying a function to each row in turn. The function that is actually being applied is an anonymous function indicated by the keyword *lambda*, which takes a single input *row* and which is fed a single row at a time from the *apply* method. That anonymous function simply calls your function *func* and passes the two column values in the row.

A Series can be summed using the *sum* function.

Note the indexing of the columns starts at 0.

Also note, saying for x in df: will iterate over the columns.

Comment: Its working fine! Thanks for the help. Appreciate your comments :)

Answer (score 0):

your number one problem is the following line:

`for i in df_weather:` This line is actually yielding you the column titles and not the rows themselves. What you're looking for is actually the following:

`for i in df_weather.values():`. The `values` will return a numpy array that you could itterate. The problem though is that the variable `i` will be a single row in the matrix now.

Comment: Or, DataFrame.iterrows, DataFrame. itertuples